# how to use ImageMagick's api for php to split gif picture?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gif, imagick

I want to split a gif and i require the first frame.Now i use php api for ImageMagick.
I write the following code,but the code return complete picture.

```
function imagemagick_auto_img($inputImg,$dstWidth,$dstHeight) {
          try {

                    $im = new Imagick($inputImg);
                    $im = $im->coalesceImages();
                    $outputData = array('width'=> $dstWidth, 'height' => $dstHeight);

                    foreach ($im as $frame) {
                      $frame->thumbnailImage($outputData['width'],$outputData['height']);
                      $frame->writeImages($createImg, true);
                      return $createImg;
                    }
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                    $createImg = $this->autoImgThumbs($inputImg,$dstWidth, $dstHeight);
            }

}
```